# Translation for “as it is”

Tags: translation

I would like to know if there is a chinese translation for “as it is” used in the following context.

If you are paying for an item in the supermarket and the staff offers you a shopping bag, but you decline the bag and want the item “as it is”. How would you say it?

The japanese have a phrase for it: そのままで、 which translates to “as it is”. Would you have a chinese translatiom for this?

Comment: some users are more accustomed to "as is" for which online translators supply 原样

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chinese does not have a exact translation of そのままで (其の儘で) which is as flexible as the situation that you've described. The literal translations are

- 照原樣
- 依舊

which both mean something like *in accord with its original nature/form*, but we would not use those terms to decline a shopping bag. Instead, you may say something similar to the following in casual vernacular:

1. 不用了 (*No need*)
2. 這樣就行了 (*It'll be fine like this*)

(2) matches そのままで fairly well in meaning in this case.

Comment: How about “就这样”?

Answer (score 2):

To decline offer of bag, I would probably say:  我不需要袋子，谢谢！; 不用袋子， 谢谢！;  不用装袋子，我用手拿着就好了。; etc.